# linker errors in Xcode 6.4 and can't fix

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I am getting these 2 errors and not sure how to fix them in Xcode 6.4

```
ld: file not found: /Users/dev1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/proj1-gamqrcytwytvxwbqssizthnsmczk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/proj1.app/proj1
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


(null): error: unable to open executable '/Users/dev1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/proj1-gamqrcytwytvxwbqssizthnsmczk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/proj1Tests.xctest/proj1Tests': No such file or directory
```

I've moved the source code to another folder. I've Cleaned the project

I'm not sure what else I can do.

Comment: Well have you checked if the executable at that path exists?

Comment: I've tried running the project in a brand new account and same error. Obviously in the new account the executable won't exist. Not sure what else can be done. I'm trying to avoid creating a new project and copying the source  files over.

Comment: now this is happening to any project i open. I am deleting Xcode and all supporting files then will reinstall. Lets see if that works